# How to use IF function in Excel to find a simple embedded term

Tags: excel-formula

I want to use Excel function to find a simple embedded term (partial find), and return another cell value. I managed to make a formula that sort of works, but I want to know if:

1. there is a more efficient formula to accomplish the same thing; and

Here is the formula: `=IF(VLOOKUP("*"&B1,A6:B12,1,FALSE)="S-"&B1,VLOOKUP("*"&B1,A6:B12,2,FALSE), Not Found)` This formula returns the value in B2 in the picture below.

2. A question/problem I have is that the wildcard "*" works in VLOOKUP but not in IF, so I'm stuck with manually entering the string "S-". Luckily the array i'm working with uses the same term ("S-") for all values, but that might change in the future and I'd like a way to deal with that. This causes the formula not to work when there is text after the number, as in the last cell in the example.

[image]

Comment: so if in B1 you put `51` you want to return the `X051M`?

Comment: @ScottCraner that is correct. But "Text" represents various characters. Each cell in Column 1 & 2 are unique there are never duplicates. So some of the values in column 1 will have text after the numbers that needs to be disregarded in the formula.